# Sorting Pandas Series by unnamed value rather than index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series that has 1 index(Countries) and one unnamed column with average values. I want to sort the series in descending order based on the values instead of the index. This is what the series looks like currently: [image]

Comment: [pandas.Series.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
series.sort_values(ascending=False)
```